# Avoid "where" clause grouping when applying multiple where clauses inside the same scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this scope in my Model:

```
function extraFiltersScope($query){
    $query->where('first_name', 'test')->orWhere('name', 'testing');
    return $query;
}
```

I'm applying the clause like this:

$query = User::where('age', 30')->extraFilters()->toSql();

Expected SQL would be:

`select * from users where age=30 and first_name='test' or name='testing'`

I'm getting this:

`select * from users where age=30 and (first_name='test' or name='testing')`

It seems that that's the normal behavior since both "where" clauses are being applied inside the same scope. Is there a workaround to tell the builder to now group them?

Of course, my logic is much more complex than this, otherwise I could simply have a scope method for each one. I need to apply several filters on the same scope but without nesting.

Thanks.

Comment: what database are you using? I can only get the grouped output if I group the wheres

Comment: lagbox, I edited heavily the question. I found the cause of the problem, now I need to know if there's a workaround for the default behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Both those SQL queries are exactly the same; `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. You can test this yourself: `SELECT 1=1 AND 2=2 OR 3=4` returns 1.

Answer (score -1):

Try using DB::raw

```
    $query->where(DB::raw("( age = 30 and first_name = 'test')"))
           ->where("name", "=", testing)
    return $query;
```

Comment: Sorry but I guess your answer is exactly what I don't want to do. I want to avoid parenthesis. 

This is the SQL I need:
select * from users where age=30 and first_name='test' or name='testing'

Comment: I have edited the previous answer. I think using it should work